# Why did the Ghostbusters (2016) hair turn white?

Tags: ghostbusters-2016

At the climax of the film, two characters go through a dimensional portal and re-emerge on Earth, their hair having turned white. There seems to be no explanation as to why this occurred.

Is there any reason given in the film for this? Perhaps it was a payoff from a scene that ended up deleted?

Comment: Because it was very scary where they went?

Comment: There's nothing in the official novelisation. It just says "*Holtzmann and Patty ran over to help them. Both were covered in ectoplasm and looked bewildered. Also, their hair had turned stark white.
“Oh!” Patty said, looking at their hair.*" and that's it. No explanation. No nothing.

Comment: @Valorum you're paraphrasing right? Please say right...

Comment: and I don't recall them being covered in slime in the film : \

Comment: @MacCooper - This is possibly the single worst movie novelisation I've ever read. And I've read the novelisation for Super Mario Bros. Heck, even the novel for MiBII was better written.

Comment: : ( - not sure about the downvote. With no comment as to how to make the question better, I'm not sure what the problem would be. It's a confusing throw away in the film with no explanation. Why would that not be a valid question?

Comment: People actually paid money to see this crap? 

Comment: Is...is this really asking why the classic scared hair white trope?

Comment: ? @Broklynite - I think the question is clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any obvious in-universe explanation other than that they've been to the spooky realm and that it [scared their hair white](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LockedIntoStrangeness).

You may wish to note that this isn't, however, the first time in the Ghostbusters franchise that a character has traveled to a ghouslish dimension and returned with white hair.

[image]
<sub><sup>[RGB: The Hole in the Wall Gang](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hole_in_the_Wall_Gang)</sup></sub>

Comment: I like this reference! My only other thought was that it was a shout out to Winston's line in the original "I've seen sh*t that will turn you white"

Comment: Interesting note: The episode shown in the clip was written by David Gerrold - most famous for writing 'The Trouble with Tribbles' from Star Trek

Answer (score 1):

I always assumed that it was due to the fact that their Hair is actually dead, thus, when passing through the ghost world, the hair changes to white.

Of course, the fingernails, teeth, and dead layer of skin would always turn white, but, fingernails are already white, or clear, the teeth, already white, and the layer of dead skin cells can easily be blown off coming through the portal, the only thing left behind would be the hair.

Seeing as the hair is dead, it become "undead" or ghostly white, as it was a dead thing returning from the world of the dead. Thanks my best theory.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the movie appears to involve some time travel, or something similar to time travel:

[image]

> Rowan's spookification of New York City brings back ghosts from throughout the city's past: The Ghostbusters battle an Uncle Sam on stilts, vintage Macy's parade balloons, and pilgrims, among others. This makes sense; typically, ghosts are from the past. But in the shot above, all of Times Square is made to look the way it did in the 70s (apparently 1976, judging by the ad for *Taxi Driver* in the top left). The movie isn't clear about what's going on here: Maybe the city has been sent back in time. Maybe everybody in the city has been sent back in time. Maybe what we're seeing is *the ghost of Times Square.*

The timing of when the characters enter and exit the portal is significant:

> Abby and Erin enter the portal while the city is still in 70s mode. Their struggle with Giant Ghost Rowan within the portal takes place while the portal is closing and the Mercado is re-assembling itself. When they pop back into the real world, it's the 21st century again.

If we interpret the large-scale transfomation as a form of time travel, rather than possession or some other ghostly phenomenon, the change in hair color can be explained like this:

> Abby and Erin entered the portal ca. 1976 and exited in 2016 (or whenever the movie takes place). Their hair turned white because they had rapidly "aged" forty years.

Obviously this is a very cartoonish version of what would really happen if two women really entered a ghost portal under these circumstances, but it seems that the intent of the filmmakers was to depict the effects of time travel.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a possible reference to Danny Phantom? It's very clearly laid out that in the show, Danny went into a portal that was supposed to lead to the Ghost Zone, and it didn't work at first until he hit a button inside the area to the portal and was basically electrocuted portal's energy and this embedded ectoplasm in his DNA. To quote the show, "when he first woke up he realized he had snow white hair and glowing green eyes".

Hair turning suddenly white is called "Marie Antoinette Syndrome" after reports that her hair turned pure white on three separate occasions, including the flight to Varennes and is very rare, but triggered by extreme stress. Other characters in media that have had this happen to them are Kaneki Ken (from Tokyo Ghoul after 12 days of torture) and Allen Walker (from D. Gray-Man after his dead father returned from the dead and tried to kill him but cursed him instead). This can be applied also to Danny Fenton as he was basically electrocuted and half-killed. That's pretty much extreme stress.

Now going through a portal and coming back does not contain the same stress that the other events where Marie-Antoinette Syndrome happens, so my guess is that one of the writers had seen Danny Phantom, and since it was a ghost-related show, used it for inspiration, as there is a Ghost Zone and portal to that said Ghost Zone in both Ghost Busters 2016 and Danny Phantom. (Also one device is called a thermos in Ghost Busters 2016 and a common device in Danny Phantom was the Fenton Thermos, both sucked in and contained ghosts.)

TL;DR: Ghost Busters 2016 took inspiration from Danny Phantom for the portal scene.

(Also I haven't seen the original in a very long time so I hope this all makes sense.)

Comment: Can you offer confirmation that that's where the filmmakers drew inspiration from?

Comment: I appreciate the effort but, without some proof, that's going to be too much of a stretch for me to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but it seems simply like it is an effect of the portal. Erin and Abbey are struck by some sort of lightning or energy discharge twice. The first time affects their hair slightly, then the second, larger strike fully lightens their hair. So, that's the why.

I guess a new question could be 'what is the discharge that changes their hair?' **

** I hope the extended edition has either a deleted scene or some sort of featurette or commentary that may explain, but I don't have that version yet, just the standard digital edition.

Answer (score -1):

I think that when they both look back at the same time, they witness something that turns their hair whit. They can't comprehend what they saw, or maybe they didn't realize they saw something. It feels like, the Zuul scene at the end can lead to a sequel. Maybe they didn't realize Zuul was there, but Zuul saw them and marked them for his return by changing their hair. What if the recording at the end that Patty is listening to was captured while Abby and Erin were in the portal? Whose to say their packs don't have some sort of built in recording device? All that together feels like it can be a very possible theory at least to me.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE This seems like speculation, please try to back your answer up with references from the source material.

Answer (score -2):

I will bet anyone a gazillion dollars that NKCampbell is spot on and this was simply a reference to Winston's statement about sh*t that will turn you white from the original.  That was precisely the reason I laughed when I saw them emerge with the white hair.  Personally, I think it was the most clever joke in the whole film.

Comment: Opinions are not really what we are looking for on this website and you don't need a separate answer to say you agree with someone.  Maybe a little later, when you've earned some rep, you can comment this sort of thing.

Comment: Got it.  I'll stick to stating facts about fiction.  Thank you for putting me in my place.